# Primefaces p:menu all icons jumps to submenu

Tags: primefaces, tomcat7

I'm using:

- primefaces 3.4
- tomcat7
- using custom primefaces theme (dark-hive)
- firefox 16.0.2, IE8

I am trying put p:menu to website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      >
    <body>

        <ui:composition>
            <h:form>
                <p:menu >  
                    <p:submenu label="TESTING" icon="ui-icon-disk">  
                        <p:menuitem value="TEST"  outcome="/jsp/home" icon="ui-icon-star"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="List" outcome="/jsp/rip/home2" /> 
                        <p:menuitem value="ExcelTEst" outcome="/jsp/excelTest" /> 
                    </p:submenu>  
                </p:menu>

            </h:form>
        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

In this example icon ui-icon-star jumps to submenu Testing left upper coner. Also this happens for all icons, which I add for menuitems.
As for icon ui-icon-disk, it doesn't show up.

I tried several other examples. 
This worked:

```
<p:panelMenu style="width:200px">  

    <p:submenu label="Navigations" >  
        <p:submenu label="Links" icon="ui-icon-extlink">  
            <p:submenu label="PrimeFaces" icon="ui-icon-heart">  
                <p:menuitem value="Home" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-home" />  
                <p:menuitem value="Docs" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" icon="ui-icon-document" />  
                <p:menuitem value="Download" url="http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" />  
                <p:menuitem value="Support" url="http://www.primefaces.org/support.html" icon="ui-icon-wrench" />  
            </p:submenu>  
        </p:submenu>  
        <p:menuitem value="Mobile" icon="ui-icon-signal"/>  
    </p:submenu>  
</p:panelMenu>
```

Can someone say, what's wrong? Why p:menu doesn't work as expected?

[image]

Comment: You mean `p:menu`? If so, please correct your post. Could you include a screenshot, browser version?

Comment: Hi @akoskm I updated my question, but I cant give image here. I don't have much reputation :)

Comment: SOLVED I removed theme from ThemeRoller and replaced it with theme from Primefaces. Can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
Removed theme from ThemeRoller and took theme from Primefaces. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right solution, just fix in your custom theme css:

```
.ui-menu .ui-icon 
    position: absolute; /* remove this line */
    top: .2em;
    left: .2em;
}

to

.ui-menu .ui-icon 
     top: .2em;
    left: .2em;
}
```