# ThemeRoller doesn't style <p:tabView> and <p:menuBar> correctly

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, themeroller

Primefaces 3.5.10

If I am using ThemeRoller generated themes, I found that not all components are styled correctly. E.g. `<p:tabView>` and `<p:menuBar>`. If I use tabView in a dialog, all tabs content are shown on one page. If I switch to any tab, then the content for every tab will be shown properly, not more as one big page with all tabs content.

If I use icons in menuBar all icons are shown on top in one place.

I've tried many themes from Themeroller but the result is always the same. Do you know some CSS hacks to correct this behaviour ? Or what can I do in this situation?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14268236/1692632

Comment: @Darka Yes, I know that primefefaces themes function correctly. But I want to create new theme) A simple way is Themeroller